# Loop thru background-images onClick working—but only on secondClick

Tags: javascript, css, loops, onclick

I want to cycle the background-image and background-color on click between two different themes (eg. daytime mode and nighttime mode.) I'm using the following code, which works, but there are two issues:

1. The function only changes the background on the second click. The first click on the link doesn't change the background css.
2. I only have two background images/colors I want to cycle between, but I don't know how to make the code cycle between two, so I have a long array that will eventually break.

Code:

```
var allImages = ["bg-clouds.png", "bg-cloudsNight.png", "bg-clouds.png", "bg-cloudsNight.png", "bg-clouds.png"];

var allColors = ["#b7d9ef", "#011157", "#b7d9ef", "#011157", "#b7d9ef"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#theLink").click(function() {
        var newImageLink = allImages.pop();
        var newColor = allColors.pop();
        $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + newImageLink + ")");
        $("body").css("background-color", "" + newColor + "");
    });
});
```

Can you let me know why the function only works on the second click?

PS: You can see it in action at ewb.atworq.com/permagoo/ (#theLink is in the top left corner)

Comment: You should not rely on that array. Do some math so you can tell what to do on a click. How about this: set a 'data-time="night" when you change to night. If you find that on the body, take it off and switch to day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a slightly different approach that will fix the first-click problem and let you cycle the colors forever.

Add something like the following to your page template:

```
<style>
.daytime {
   background-image: url('bg-clouds.png');
   background-color: #b7d9ef;
}
.nighttime {
   background-image: url('bg-cloudsNight.png');
   background-color: #011157;
}
</style>
```

Then edit your template or whatever to say: `<body class="daytime">` when the page is rendered

Now you'll be able to switch both the image and color just by changing the classname from `daytime` to `nighttime` like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#theLink').click(function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('daytime nighttime');
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The call to `.toggleClass()` will remove any classes that exist on the element (`daytime` will exist on the first `click`) and add any classes that do not exist (`nighttime` will be added).

Comment: You could simplify it slightly and rather than having a `daytime` class, just have that be the default style, then all you need to do is `toggleClass('nighttime')`.

Comment: Yes! So sensible. Thank you. And @ultranaut I also took your suggestion into account. Regrettably, and strangely enough, this does not in IE8! I have the code implemented [here](http://ewb.atworq.com/permagoo/). I'm already very appreciative for the insight, and I'll continue debugging, but perhaps someone has a thought on what to change for IE.

Comment: If you're having trouble make sure to include the `return false;` which I forgot to mention earlier, and also use `z-index` or some other css technique to keep the button on top of other elements. Without that you may find yourself clicking on an `<h1>` or something instead of the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your code on the site.. and you are correct that you will two large arrays of repeating values - this is not the way to write good code (sorry).  I would recommend something similar to what was suggested by Ryan953, but it seems you wish to accomplish this without adding classes to your CSS file.  So here is a working example of what I would do which allows many background images..

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>background image and color cycle</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var allImages = [
                "http://ewb.atworq.com/permagoo/theworks/dreaming2012/images/bg-clouds.png", 
                "http://ewb.atworq.com/permagoo/theworks/dreaming2012/images/bg-cloudsNight.png",
                "http://degnedyrlaegen.dk/picts/background-header.jpg"
            ];

        var allColors = [ "#b7d9ef", "#011157", "#a1e35b" ];

        var current = 0;

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#theLink").click(function() {
                $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + allImages[current] + ")").css("background-repeat","repeat-x");
                $("body").css("background-color", "" + allColors[current] + "");
                current = (current++ < allImages.length - 1) ? current : 0 ;
            });
        });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>background image and color cycle</h2>
    <button id="theLink">cycle background</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You can copy and paste above code in a local HTML file and run it locally - it should work. :)

Comment: I like this solution better than what I had proposed :) I can't get it to work on my server though. I can't see what would be wrong with the code. Thanks for your feedback. It may be useful for others or I may get it working myself.